# How to access Map modified in RDD, in the driver program of Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, driver, rdd

Need help.

I am working on Apache Spark 1.2.0. I have a requirement or rather I should say I am stuck in some issue.

Its like :-

I am running a map function on RDD in which I am creating some Object instances and storing those instances in a ConcurrentMap against some key. Now after Map function has finished I need data that was stored in ConcurrentMap in the driver program. Which as of now is blank outside the map function.

Is it at all possible ? Can I access it by any means ?

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: You should post some code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misusing Spark or misunderstanding the concept. The thing you want to do can be achieved with `mapPartitions` function. This function will provide you an iterator over all the rows in the input RDD partition, this way you would know when the processing has finished and would be able to either save the `ConcurrentMap` you've generated to persistent storage or return its `iterator` as the function result

It you would elaborate on your use case or attach the code, I would be able to recommend the right solution for you